# procedimiento almacenado que valide rango de horas

Tags: sql-server

soy nuevo en esto de los procedimientos almacenados y no se como validar un rango de horas.
tengo una base de datos con edificio, piso y cuartos ademas de los trabajadores que son los que pueden "apartar" un cuarto...
lo que no logro hacer es que desde el procedimiento almacenado valide el que no registre los datos cuando el cuarto esta ocupado, es decir, de 3:00:00 a 4:00:00 ya esta ocupado que nadie mas pueda ocupar la.

nose si soy claro en mi problemática

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias...

Comment: Por favor, en lugar de imágenes, copia y pega el código original en la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses datetime2(0) (o datetime, smalldetatime), en vez de separar fecha y hora. La consulta tiene algunos problemas, por lo que podríamos dar las mejores opciones si compartes texto en vez de imágenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al igual que indica Rafael, no pegues imagenes, copia el codigo del Store Procedure y pegalo.

No obstante, el proble es que deberias comprobar con un IF si tienes un IDSalasJuntas valido que no este entre las horas, algo asi

DECLARE @IDSalaJuntasLibre int

--Seleccionas si el registro esta ocupado
SELECT @IDSalaJuntasLibre = IDSalaJuntas FROM Prestamo WHERE fecha BETWEEN ...

--Si el campo es null esta libre, o puedes hacer la consulta anterior al reves
IF @IDSalaJuntasLibre IS NULL BEGIN